# Sharepoint Calculated Column Get Date from Year, Week and Day Number

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I want a user to be able to enter a work year, week and day number (starting on monday) in a field, and then output a date to a calculated field.

I have seen similar questions to this, but not one this comprehensive.

For example:

1819.3 -> 5/9/18 (18=yr, 19=wk, 3=day)

1820.1 -> 5/14/18 (18=yr, 20=wk, 1=day)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the input value will be in this same format everytime then you can use a substring function to make it working in your case.

Generate a column and write a function to get a substring from the string